# add a month to date in php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin

```
$appointment=$_POST['appointment_date'];// 02/09/2014(d/m/Y)
  echo $newDate = date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+1 month',$appointment));
```

I want to add one month to this date .

Its showing some error msg A non well formed numeric value encountered.
$newDate value displaying like this 01/02/1970.

Comment: Well the problem is $appointent isn't a timestamp..

Comment: please give me solution for this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Below:

```
$appointment    =   "02/09/2014"; //dd mm YY
$pieces = explode("/", $appointment);
$timestamp = $pieces[1] ."/". $pieces[0] ."/". $pieces[2];
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+1 month',strtotime($timestamp)));
```

Result:

```
02/10/2014
```

[See here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/d3wa-qk67)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the DateTime object to do this. 
First start the DateTime object using the static 'DateTime::createFromFormat()' method.

```
$DateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '02/09/2014');
$DateTime->modify('+1 month'); //add a month
```

And finally output it

```
echo $DateTime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```